# Ocultar Div desde otro

Tags: jquery

tengo en mi pagina html, un div llamado div_Date, dentro de el tengo un iframe(aqui tengo una pagina 
 "Demo"), lo que deseo y si se puede, es dentro de la pagina "Demo", puedo ocultar el div_Date, alguna sugerencia? con jquery

```
<div id='div_Date'> 
    <iframe src="url">paginaDemo </iframe> 
</div>
```

Lo que deseo es desde la paginaDemo al ejecutar cierta instrucción ocultar el div_Date que en este caso es mi contenedor, lo he intentado con jquery de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#container').contents().find('#div_Date').hide()
```

container es el div principal de mi pagina de inicio html

Comment: Hola!...te sugiero que agregues algo de código, estructura bien tu pregunta colocando ejemplos de que tienes y que deseas hacer. Y claro que se puede, pero debes de esforzarte un poco más para plantear bien tu pregunta y así darte una respuesta que te ayude a ti, y a la comunidad.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es usar show y hide:

```
$('#id').hide();//Oculatar Elementos
$('#id').show();//Mostrar Elementos
```

Una forma alternativa es usar el método jQuery css :

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
$("#id").css("display", "block");
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery)